# How to change the position of Materialize Tooltips to the top left?

Tags: css, materialize

I am trying to position a materialize CSS tooltip to the top left of an HTML form label. There is currently an option to add to a data-position attribute, but it only positions to the top, left, bottom or right.

As you can see, the tooltip is positioned to the top, but it I add negative left spacing, e.g. `left: -200px`, it doesn't make any difference.

```
.material-tooltip {
  padding: 10px 8px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 36px;
  line-height: 120%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #5a99ce;
cursor: pointer!important
}

<label class="tooltipped" for="company-name" data-position="left" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip">*Company name<i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></label>
```

I would like the tooltip to be aligned to the top left of the form label

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed setting `left` doesn't do anything, however in my tests using `margin-left` seems to do what you need.

```
.material-tooltip
{
    padding: 10px 8px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    z-index: 2000;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 36px;
    line-height: 120%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: calc(100% - 4px);
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #323232;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```